# make turret move following the tank position

Tags: xna

i'm starting my game assignment in XNA c#. I am making a 2d tank shooting game.

Now i trying to make my turret move together with my tank. My tank class "Has A" turret entity, and i'm drawing my turret in my tank class. Now i wanted to make my turret move with my tank. I'm passing in my tank position to my turret class (tank and turret is in different class), and update in my turret class, but my turret did not shows up when i build and run the game.

I attach my code below for anyone help that is kind to lend me a hand and point out where i got wrong.

My game code structure:
sprite.cs - the main class
player.cs and turret.cs - child class of sprite.cs
game1.cs - the game class

Turret.cs

```
class Turret:Sprite
{   
    //public Vector2 turretPosition, origin;
    //public Texture2D texture;
    //string textureName;
    Player player;

    public Turret()
    {}

    public Turret(Vector2 pos):
        base(pos)
    {
        //turretPosition = pos;
        this.textureName = "Turret";
    }

    public void updatePosition(Vector2 pos)
    {
        this.position.X += pos.X;
        this.position.Y += pos.Y;

    }

    public void init()
    {
        player = new Player(position);
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        init();
        this.position.X += player.getPosition().X;
        this.position.Y += player.getPosition().Y;

        base.Update();
    }



}
```

}

player.cs(this is the tank class)

Player:Sprite
    {

```
    KeyboardState keyboard , prevKeyboard;
    float friction = 0.1f;
    public Turret turret;
    public Player(Vector2 pos)
        : base(pos)
    {
        position = pos;
        speed = 5;
        textureName = "Tank11";

        turret = new Turret(this.position);

    }

    public Vector2 getPosition()
    {
        return this.position;
    }       

    public override void Update()
    {

        //REMEMBER TO CALL your turret.Update() here if u implemented override update function in turrent class.
        //update turret position;
       // turret.Update();


        keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        //origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

        if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            rotation -= 0.1f ;
        if(keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            rotation += 0.1f ;
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            velocity.X = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * speed;
            velocity.Y = -(float)Math.Cos(rotation) * speed;
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            velocity.X = -(float)Math.Sin(rotation) * speed;
            velocity.Y = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * speed;
        }
        else if (velocity != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            float i = velocity.X;
            float j = velocity.Y;

            velocity.X = i -= friction * i;
            velocity.Y = j -= friction * j;
        }



        position += velocity;

        prevKeyboard = keyboard;
        base.Update(); 
    }

    public override void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
         turret.LoadContent(content);
         base.LoadContent(content);
    }

    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        var turretOffSet = new Vector2(0, 0);

        base.Draw(spriteBatch);
        turret.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }

}
```

Sprite.cs (the main class)

```
 Sprite
{
    protected Vector2 position, origin, velocity;
    protected Texture2D texture;
    protected float speed = 0.0f;
    protected float rotation = 0.0f;
    protected float scale = 1.0f;
    protected string textureName;

    public Sprite()
    { }

    public Sprite(Vector2 pos)
    {
        position = pos;
        speed = 0.0f;
        rotation = 0.0f;
    }

    public virtual void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        //textureName = name;
        texture = content.Load<Texture2D>("Image\\" + this.textureName);
    }

    public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        Rectangle size;
        origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, null, Color.White, rotation, origin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {

    }

    public void pushTo(float spd, float dir)
    {
        // XNA Client Space is in the opposite quadrant of the positive rotation quadrant
        float newX = -(float)Math.Cos(dir);
        float newY = -(float)Math.Sin(dir);

        position.X += spd * (float)newX;
        position.Y += spd * (float)newY;
    }
}
```

hope tat someone here who read it can point out where did i done wrong....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking others to debug your code, which is not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling init in your turret's Update method, which sets the player property to a new instance.  I don't see how your turret instance knows about its tank instance in order to read the current position value.

```
public class Turret
{
    private Player player;

    public Turret(Player parent)
    {
        // Store a reference to the parent player instance
        this.player = parent;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
        // Read current parent player position
        var p = player.Position;

        ...
    }

    ...
}

public class Player
{
    private Turret turret;

    // Allow turret to access the position of the player
    public Vector2 Position { get { return position; } }

    public Player()
    {
        // Pass reference to this parent instance into the new turret
        turret = new Turret(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooohh... my bad..... Thank you for your sincere reminder... it help me fixed the problem... now the turret is on top of the tank... but the turret is like being "drag" along on top of the tank...